# Computing the coefficient of $x^n$ in the following expansion

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, contest-math

The coefficient of $x^{-n}$ in the expansion of $\frac{2-3x}{1-3x+2x^2}$ is

$a.)$ $(-3)^n - (2)^{\frac{1}{2}n -1} $

$b.)$ $2^n + 1 $

$c.)$ $ 3(2)^{\frac{1}{2}n - 1} - 2(3)^n $

$d.)$ None of the foregoing numbers.

My attempt :
First of all I concluded that the question must be asking about coeff. to the power of -n , not n as mentioned because x only appears in the denominator.

I was able to reduce the given expression to the following separated fractions : $ \frac{1}{1-2x} $ and $ \frac{1}{1-x} $. Since both the terms contain x it must be the case that the total power of each term in the binomial expansion must be -n. 
Hence my answer turned out to be $2^n$. The correct option as indicated is option b.)

Please tell me where am I going wrong in my method, and suggest a better method to solve the following problem.

Comment: I think they mean the taylor coefficients? Say you expand the function around $0$, then I think they are looking for $\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$, not the coefficient of $x^{-n}$ in a polynomial expansion...Try computing the derivatives of $\frac{1}{1-2x}$ and $\frac{1}{1-x}$. You should see a pattern and be able to deduce the correct answer.

Comment: Hmm didn't think of that possibility , maybe they do . 
I guess the only to check would be to see if that gives the correct answer .

Comment: I added a little bit of an outline of how to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial fraction decomposition is a proper method to answer the question. It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^n$ of a series.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> [x^n]\frac{2-3x}{1-3x+2x^2}&=[x^n]\left(\frac{1}{1-2x}+\frac{1}{1-x}\right)\tag{1}\\
> &=[x^n]\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(2x)^j+[x^n]\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}x^j\tag{2}\\
> &=2^n+1
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use partial fraction decomposition
- In (2) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and the *[geometric series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)* from which the coefficient of $x^n$ can easily be obtained.

*Note:* Since no explicit statement about the center of series expansion is formulated, we may assume an expansion around $x=0$ is expected.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in your division of the polynomials. They are asking for the taylor coefficients in the power series expansion of the function. Let $f(x) = \frac{1}{1-2x}$ and $g(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}$. Then
\begin{align*}
    f'(x) = \frac{2}{(1-2x)^2}\\
    f''(x) = \frac{2\times 2^2}{(1-2x)^3}\\
    f^{(3)}(x) = \frac{6\times 2^3}{(1-2x)^4}\\
    f^{(n)}(x) = \frac{n!\times 2^n}{(1-2x)^{n+1}}\\
\end{align*}
and similarly you can see that $g^{(n)}(x) = \frac{n!}{(1-x)^{n+1}}$. Expanding the function around $0$ will give you the right answer; your function is $F(x) = f(x) + g(x)$ so that 
    $$F(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{F^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0) + g^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n$$

Comment: I want to know , what made you consider expanding the function at point zero ? Why not  expand at any other point ?

Comment: because it is easy to see what the coefficient of $x^n$ is.

Comment: Looking at it other way, since choice of $x_0$  does not affect the required coif. we may as well assume it to be 0 . Am I right @John Martin

Comment: That is the idea, yes. And the function is nicely behaved in a neighborhood of 0 so we are able to do that.